# Make new branch, and keep edits

Tags: git

The only workflow I've used is

```
branch -> (write code -> commit)*n -> merge
```

I made a mistake though and am now

```
master -> write code
```

I am afraid if I

```
... -> branch
```

I will lose my edits, which are unstable.

true or false?

Comment: you will not lose your edits as long as branch you are switching to is new and doesn't have any upstream changes.

Comment: Also, have a peek at the `git stash` command http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Stashing

Comment: @Eimantas so, git branch new, git checkout new, git commit will work?

Comment: @chris I am sure this is the correct answer, I will look into it later, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you are afraid of loosing changes, commit them. (Once you did a commit, git will never forget. If you do not commit git does not know about the changes and cannot help you.)

In your case simply doing something like `git checkout -b mybranch` should be fine.

The other way is `git commit`, `git branch mybranch`, `git reset --hard HEAD^`.

First (as I wrote in the beginning) commit everything important. Second give the current branch the correct name. Third reset master to where it belongs to. (If you did only one commit `HEAD^` is fine. If you have defined some upstream `@{u}` would be also fine.)

If you are not exactly sure what is going on, have a look at `gitk --all`. This should nicely visualize exactly what happens.

Answer (score 0):

If you are switching to a new branch, the working copy won't be affected, so you can just do

```
git checkout -b anewbranch
```

and then add and commit whatever you like.

Generally speaking, Git simply won't allow you to switch to a branch if you have uncommitted changes in your working copy that would be overridden. In such cases you can temporarily store away the working copy, checkout a branch and finally restore it.

```
git stash
git checkout anotherbranch 
git stash pop
```